# QGIS Python API set label color based on attribute field

Tags: qgis, python, color, text

I'm trying to set the text label **color** and **size** based on the attribute table. I got the size setting correctly but not the color.

My current result looks like this (The symbol has been set to be transparent), and I want to give different colors to different text labels.

[image]

The attribute table looks like this:

[image]

The code is as following:

```
vlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
vlayer.renderer().symbol().setOpacity(0.0)

pc=QgsPropertyCollection('Text')
color_prop=QgsProperty()
color_prop.setField("color")

size_prop = QgsProperty()
size_prop.setField("size")
pc.setProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Color,color_prop)
pc.setProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size,size_prop)

label_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
text_format = QgsTextFormat()

label_settings.setDataDefinedProperties(pc)

label_settings.fieldName = 'name'
label_settings.setFormat(text_format)

vlayer.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label_settings))
vlayer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
vlayer.triggerRepaint()
```

I wonder where is wrong with the color setting in the code? My best guess is that the color field in the attribute table is not what QGIS requires, but I'm not sure what should be the correct format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace spaces in `color` value to commas. `100 150 0` -> `100,150,0`

Or change

```
color_prop.setField("color")
```

into

```
color_prop.setExpressionString("replace(trim(color), ' ', ',')")
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You need to put comma separator between the RGB color in the color field in the attribute table, and the code will work perfectly:

[image]

I did not change anything in the code.